# Steam: Strange Trading Verification Bug

Tags: steam

Recently, I've been running into this bug with the verification code on the trading(The one that confirms you're not a robot). The part of the window with the letters that I need to type appears too short, which blocks out part of the code I need. I wouldn't be surprised if this can't be fix by something I do, but if it can, please help! If not,] I would at least like to know how to report this to steam or something.[image]

Comment: We may want to close this question as Steam has changed the Trade interface twice more since this question came out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the software in question no longer works this way.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to try again as Steam just switched CAPTCHAs an hour or two ago due to the one it implemented yesterday [already being broken by item-stealing Malware](https://twitter.com/SteamDB/status/554046036813963264).